# CLLocationManager is not recognized

Tags: ios, cllocationmanager

I try to initialize and use the `CLLocationManager` instance in my code,

when I remove the comment of this code block,

```
locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
```

I have taken an error

```
_OBJC_CLASS_$_CLLocationManager", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in ApothekeViewController.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
```

What is the problem?

Comment: Have you linked against the CoreLocation framework?

Comment: oopss, i thought, mapkit is enough for all of them. thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're gong to need to link against the Core Location framework for each of your targets that use that code.

In your project file in Xcode (blue file at the top), select one of your targets from the second-to-the-right pane. In the summary tab, there is a frameworks section. Select the plus button and find the Core Location framework.